# How to override magrittr pipe operator?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Say I have a data set and I'd like to apply several filters to it using piping syntax, like so:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
mtcars %<>% 
  filter(cyl == 4) %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg)
nrow(mtcars)
#[1] 11
```

I check the current status of the data set with `nrow` after each such step, so I thought I could override the piping `%<>%` operator along the lines of

```
`%<?>%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  x <- magrittr::`%<>%`(lhs, rhs)
  if (is.data.frame(x) & pipeVerbose) print(nrow(x))
}
#Using this will generate errors like
#Error in pipes[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
```

And now by switching `pipeVerbose` flag on or off I would control the tracking procedure for the whole flow. Apparently it's not that simple because of the internal evaluation mechanism, as prompted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43786599/error-in-magrittr-pipe-when-using-magrittr). The question is, is it possible to achieve the desired behavior with minimal effort, i.e. without patching the `magittr` internals?

I have to admit the whole idea is slightly unsettling, but my actual scenario is a bit more complicated and I'd like to hide some debug/development details for demonstration purposes via a simple on/off switch.

Comment: If I understand well, you'd like to print the output of nrow on each step of the pipe?

Comment: @ColinFAY Not quite; only when reassignment with `%<>%` takes place, and without appending extra pipe steps like `%>% nrow` everywhere.

Comment: Possibly related: [rmonad](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmonad/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since chains take advantage of lazy evaluation, a better translation would have been something like this:

```
`%<?>%` <- function(lhs, rhs) {
  call <- match.call()
  call[[1]] <- quote(`%<>%`)
  x <- eval.parent(call)
  if (is.data.frame(x) & pipeVerbose) print(nrow(x))
}
```

We basically re-write the function call and evaluate it.

Answer (score 3):

You could make use of a `TaskCallback` which executes whenever a toplevel task is completed. In the callback check if the expression contains the `%<>%` operator and if yes print the result:

```
printAssignmentPipe <- function(exp, res, success, printed){

  if (any(grepl("%<>%", exp, fixed = T))) {
    print(res)
  }
  TRUE
}

addTaskCallback(printAssignmentPipe)
```

You can easily extend the callback to also check the value of `pipeVerbose` or you simply call `addTaskCallback` and `removeTaskCallback` to activate/deactivate.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can have you on/off switch this way, not much more visible than having `%<?>%` instead of `%<>%` :

```
p <- function(x){if(pipeVerbose) print(nrow(x))}

pipeVerbose <- FALSE
mtcars %<>% 
  filter(cyl == 4) %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg) %T>% p

rm(mtcars)
pipeVerbose <- TRUE
mtcars %<>% 
  filter(cyl == 4) %>% 
  select(cyl, mpg) %T>% p
```

Comment: Thanks; that's pretty close to what I've eventually come to.